# Intellij ignores java Compiler additional compiler options

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

I have a java 11 project which has some native functions.
I am trying to generate the corresponding Header-files by adding '-h myDir' to the additional compiler options in Intellij but it seems like IntelliJ does not even look for those.

I am going to: Files > Setting > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Additional Command line parameter

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using `javah` or `javac? In order to generate native header files, you should use `javah`.

Comment: i am using javac because i am on jdk 11 (updated above question) and javah is no longer present in the Jdk 11 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed my own problem.

Since Intellij ignored the compiler options for my jdk11 project via `Files > Setting > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Additional Command line parameter` I simply set them in gradle.build and it now runs perfectly.

In your `gradle.build` include following:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ['-h', 'absolute dir where you want to put the header files']
}
```